# Ping from aspnet application hosted on iis express

Tags: c#, asp.net, ping, iis-express

I have the following simple code:

```
var ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
var result = ping.Send("www.google.com", 120, new byte[] { }, new System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions { DontFragment = true });
```

that works like a charm if I run it in a console application or LinqPad. However if I run it from an asp.net application running locally (in debug) through IIS Express I get the following error:

> No such host is known

This no matter the address I try to ping. I am not behind any proxy. Also pinging from the command line on the same machine works correctly.

I have no clue of the reason behind this. What can be the cause?

Thanks.

Comment: No such problems here using VS2013 and IIS Express with a default ASP.NET MVC project + your code (in debug)

Comment: Did you tried pinging an other IP? Like 8.8.8.8, which is gooogles DNS-Server.